# How to have control over errors showed in login template on FosUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I am using FosUserBundle and I just want to show a few errors in the login template:

- Invalid email
- Please check your email and password

And in my login.html.twig template, I am showing the errors in this way:

```
{% if error %}
        <p style="color:red">{{ error.message }) }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

It is working fine, my problem is that I haven't a control over the errors showed in the template. For example, I was making some tests with my mysql service and I got this error in the template:

```
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

So, I want to know how to have full control of the errors and avoid any leak of other information

Answer (score 0):

More insights into login handler code would be nice to have, but I would suggest to wrap it into more try-catches and filter exceptions that you want to leak to user.